# How do I cache content and data from a json API using Rx2AndroidNetworking?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-networking, android-json, android-lru-cache

I am retrieving my response from my API with rxjava with funcs as follows:

```
@Override
public Single<MyInfoResponse> getMyInfoApiCall() {
    return Rx2AndroidNetworking.get(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINT_MY_INFO)
            .addHeaders(mApiHeader.getProtectedApiHeader())
            .build()
            .getObjectSingle(MyInfoResponse.class);
}
```

Now ,I am retrieving this data and using it in my UI code( with usual compositedisposables) as follows:

```
 @Override
    public void onViewPrepared() {
        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
                .getMyInfoApiCall()
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(myInfoResponse -> {
                    getDataManager().updateMyManagerInfo(myInfoResponse);
                    if (myInfoResponse != null && myInfoResponse.getData() != null) {
                        getMvpView().updateMyRepo(myInfoResponse.getData());
                    }

                }, throwable -> {
                    if (!isViewAttached()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    getMvpView().hideLoading();

                    // handle the error here
                    if (throwable instanceof ANError) {
                        ANError anError = (ANError) throwable;
                        handleApiError(anError);
                    }
                }));
    }
```

Now everytime I have internet connectivity and it tries to retrieve data it works fine, but as soon as I lose internet connectivity, I am trying to cache this data so it still displays on the UI until the network connectivity is back and ready to update data real time. How do I go about this in the easiest and the most ideal way possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use offline support using android Room Persistence.
Have a look at the google sample from the below link
                             https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

In this case
**Prefetch a request (so that it can return from cache when required at instant)**

```
AndroidNetworking.get("https://fierce-cove-29863.herokuapp.com/getAllUsers/{pageNumber}")
                .addPathParameter("pageNumber", "0")
                .addQueryParameter("limit", "30")
                .setTag(this)
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
            .build()
            .prefetch();
```

- First of all the server must send cache-control in header so that is
  starts working.
- Response will be cached on the basis of cache-control
  max-age,max-stale.
- If internet is connected and the age is NOT expired it will return
  from cache.
- If internet is connected and the age is expired and if server returns
  304(NOT MODIFIED) it will return from cache.
- If internet is NOT connected if you are using
  getResponseOnlyIfCached() - it will return from cache even it date is
  expired.
- If internet is NOT connected , if you are NOT using
  getResponseOnlyIfCached() - it will NOT return anything.
- If you are using getResponseOnlyFromNetwork() , it will only return
  response after validation from server.
- If cache-control is set, it will work according to the
  max-age,max-stale returned from server.
- If internet is NOT connected only way to get cache Response is by
  using getResponseOnlyIfCached().

  I just went through the docs:
  [Refer here](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking#prefetch-a-request-so-that-it-can-return-from-cache-when-required-at-instant)

Comment: is there no easy straightforward approach to this? like using setmax age or max stale cache for rx? will that work?

Comment: You can use cache, If the parameters that you are sending to the api remains the same,otherwise the result will not be the same.You can use retrofit cache mechanism. Google recommends to use the retrofit as a best practice.